# Getting configurable product id by simple product's attribute id

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.8.1.0

Every configurable product has own product id as you know.

[image: on frontend options]
[image: on admin]

When I select medium (in this example) I want to get 26, when I select large I want to get 28 etc.

I think the only way to do that using attribute id, right? How can I get product id using option's attribute id? Or another way?

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look to source code for product page you will notice something like this:

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"1162":{"id":"1162","code":"colour","label":"Colour","options":[{"id":"2197","label":"Blue","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["18577"],"image":"http:\/\/magento.localhost\/media\/amconf\/images\/2197.jpg"}],"use_image":1}},"template":"\u00a3#{price}","basePrice":"106.99","oldPrice":"106.99","productId":"18576","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":20,"currentTax":20,"inclTaxTitle":"Incl. VAT"}});
```

this is simple product id:

```
"products":["18577"]
```

call for spConfig you can find at the bottom of app/design/frontend/[your theme]/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: more than one product can have the same attribute value, you need to calculate the intersection of all selected options and compare against spConfig